# Add DOM elements on Datatables wrapper

Tags: javascript, datatables

My aim is to add buttons on a table created by datatables.js on its header.
My code to add buttons is:

```
$('#myButton').prependTo($('#myTable_wrapper'));
```

The problem is i can't find the right timing to add the button. I have tried adding the button right after the table was created but it seems like the wrapper is not yet created at that moment.
I also tried adding the button on $(document).ready() but the wrapper is also not yet  created at that part of the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myTable").datatables();
  $('#myButton').prependTo($('#myTable_wrapper'));
});
```

Where is the right part of the code to modify the wrapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the fnDrawCallback callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
                $('#myButton').prependTo($('#myTable_wrapper'));
            }
        });
});
```

Hope that works for you!

Here's a list of many other callbacks:
http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks

Good luck with this.

Comment: Very short but the best answer by Vrutin. This really helped me.

Comment: Upvoted because I was getting mad trying to operate with the wrapper. load or ready don't work as the element is not there yet.